# Who wants a hat? Come and get your hats (2016 edition)!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

'Tis the season! [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) is back on participating Stack Exchange sites.

Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

So, it's time to decide if we want hats on our Expats.SE! **Vote** on the answers below **until Friday 9 December 2016**. We'll enable hats only if there's sufficient support for it (for some yet undetermined value of "sufficient"). Please don't downvote an option, rather upvote only the one you choose. Of course, comment as necessary.

Your mod friends at Expats.SE remind you to enjoy hats responsibly.

Comment: Not sure how much the voting will be affected by my profile picture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## YES

Hats are fun and it's good to have some fun even on sites with serious topics

Comment: **YES.** Let the hat times roll!

Answer (score -1):

## NO

This is a serious site and we should not pollute it with hats